# django: How to write JavaScript fetch for url with slug parameter?

Tags: javascript, python-3.x, django, fetch-api

A django and async newbie here, trying to improve a simple message-board app. I'm sure you've all seen this problem dozens of times, but I'm unable to find a solution...

Currently, when a user likes a posted message, it refreshes the whole page. I'd like to use simple JavaScript with the fetch API to prevent this, without having to resort to Ajax, as I've never used it. The problem is, I'm very new to the fetch method as well and I'm struggling to find the correct syntax for the url in the fetch request, as it uses the post model's slug field as a parameter. Like so:

**urls.py**

```
urlpatterns = [
    ...
    path('post/<slug:slug>/', views.FullPost.as_view(), name='boards_post'), 
    path('like/<slug:slug>/', views.PostLike.as_view(), name='post_like'),
    ...
]
```

**models.py**

```
...
class Post(models.Model):
    """
    Model for message posts
    """

    STATUS = ((0, "Draft"), (1, "Published"))

    title = models.CharField(max_length=200, unique=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=200, unique=True)
    author = models.ForeignKey(
        User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="board_posts"
    )
    category = models.ForeignKey(
        Category,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        default="",
        related_name="category_posts"
    )
    created_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    content = models.TextField()
    post_image = CloudinaryField('image', default='placeholder')
    status = models.IntegerField(choices=STATUS, default=0)
    likes = models.ManyToManyField(User, related_name="post_likes")

    class Meta:
        # Orders posts in descending order
        ordering = ['-created_on']

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    def number_of_likes(self):
        return self.likes.count()

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        """
        Method to tell django how to find the url to any specific
        instance of a post when the Post model is instantiated,
        (i.e. a new post created). Returns the url generated by the
        'boards_post' path from the FullPost class view, with
        this model's slug field as a keyword argument. This
        effectively acts as a redirect to the full_post.html template.
        """

        return reverse('boards_post', kwargs={'slug': self.slug})
...
```

**views.py**

```
...
class FullPost(View):
    """
    View for a single post, selected by the user, displaying
    comments and likes. The url for each individual post is derived
    from the Post model's slug field which is, in turn,
    populated by the title.
    """

    def get(self, request, slug, *args, **kwargs):
        """
        Method to get post object.
        """

        queryset = Post.objects.filter(status=1)
        post = get_object_or_404(queryset, slug=slug)
        comments = post.comments.order_by('created_on')
        liked = False
        if post.likes.filter(id=self.request.user.id).exists():
            liked = True

        return render(
            request,
            "full_post.html",
            {
                "post": post,
                "comments": comments,
                "liked": liked,
                "comment_form": CommentForm() 
            },
        )

    def post(self, request, slug, *args, **kwargs):
        """
        Post method for comment form.
        """

        queryset = Post.objects.filter(status=1)
        post = get_object_or_404(queryset, slug=slug)
        comments = post.comments.order_by("-created_on")
        liked = False
        if post.likes.filter(id=self.request.user.id).exists():
            liked = True

        comment_form = CommentForm(data=request.POST)
        if comment_form.is_valid():
            comment_form.instance.name = self.request.user
            comment = comment_form.save(commit=False)
            comment.post = post
            comment.save()
        else:
            comment_form = CommentForm()

        return redirect(self.request.path_info)
...
...
class PostLike(View):
    """
    View for liking and unliking posts.
    """

    def post(self, request, slug):
        """
        Method to toggle liked/unliked state on a particular post.
        """

        post = get_object_or_404(Post, slug=slug)

        liked = True
        if post.likes.filter(id=self.request.user.id).exists():
            post.likes.remove(request.user)
            liked = False
        else:
            post.likes.add(request.user)

        likes = post.number_of_likes()

        # ----- The original return statement is the one commented out below:
        # return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('boards_post', args=[slug]))
        return JsonResponse({"likes": likes, "liked": liked})
...
```

**Snippet from full post template**

```
...
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-1">
    {% if user.is_authenticated %}
        <strong>
            <form class="d-inline" action="{% url 'post_like' post.slug %}" method="POST">
            {% csrf_token %}
            {% if liked %}
<!-- I used 'post.id' for the argument passed to the like function here, as I couldn't get 'post.slug' to work -->
                <button class="btn-like" type="submit" name="post_id" value="{{ post.slug }}" onclick="like({{ post.id }})">
                    <i id="like-btn" class="fas fa-thumbs-up"></i>
                </button>
                <span id="likes-count">{{ post.number_of_likes }}</span>
            {% else %}
                <button class="btn-like" type="submit" name="post_id" value="{{ post.slug }}" onclick="like({{ post.id }})">
                    <i id="like-btn" class="far fa-thumbs-up"></i>
                </button>
                <span id="likes-count">{{ post.number_of_likes }}</span>
            {% endif %}
            </form>
        </strong>
    {% else %}
        <strong class="text-secondary"><i class="far fa-thumbs-up"></i> <span id="likes-count">{{ post.number_of_likes }}</span></strong>
    {% endif %}
</div>
...
```

All I've got so far in JavaScript is the following...

```
function like(post_id) {
    let likeButton = document.getElementById("like-btn");
    let likeCount = document.getElementById("likes-count");
    
    console.log(likeCount.innerText);
    console.log(post_id);
    
    // -------- I've no idea what works here! I've tried both of the below
    // -------- and several variations.
    // -------- Obviously, none work.
    //   const url = "{%  url 'post_like' post.slug %}";
    //or const url = `/like/${post.slug}`;

    fetch(url, {method: "POST"})
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(data => {
            console.log(data);
            // ------ If I ever get the json data, I'll use it here to manipulate the
            // ------ likeButton and likeCount variables in the DOM. Something like:
            likeCount.innerHTML = data["likes"];
            if (data["liked"] === true) {
                likeButton.className = "fas fa-thumbs-up";
            } else {
                likeButton.className = "far fa-thumbs-up";
            }
        })
        .catch((e) => alert("Unable to like/unlike post."));
        // -------- or something.
}
```

Also, I know I need to handle the csrf token somehow but I've no idea how. Like I said, total newbie.
So, can anyone help? And does anyone have any advice?
Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

For `csrf_token` problem add to view this decorator:

```
from django.utils.decorators import method_decorator

@method_decorator(csrf_exempt, name='dispatch')
class PostLike(View):
    ...
```

For fetch you need to have whole path, not just relative path. This should work:

```
url = "{{ request.scheme }}://{{ request.get_host }}{% url 'post_like' post.slug %}"
```

Comment: Hey. Thanks for the response, Now it's giving me a "NoReverseMatch at /
Reverse for 'post_like' with arguments '('',)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried:" error. I'm guessing it's the slug that's the problem,

Comment: Yes, `post.slug` does not pass anything. You need to check if it in the context. Is the JS in the same file as the full template? Maybe you need to add `''` to the argument of: `onclick="like('{{ post.id }}')"`. Other thing might be that you are passing `id` to the JS function, but you seek it with `slug`. Also remember, that anything in curly braces is rendered BEFORE it can be activated it front.

Comment: Yeah, I tried all of the above. JS in the full_post template made no difference. Tried passing the slug to the function again and got the same result as I did initially - it seems to try reading the slug as a variable or something, e.g: `<first word of slug> is not defined...`

Comment: I'd have to refactor all my code to use the post's pk or id instead of its slug in the url and, frankly, I don't have the time to mess around with it right now, so I might just leave it. Good learning experience though for future reference: while the slug might look nicer in the address bar, the id definitely seems to be the more efficient way of referencing a model instance. Thanks a lot for your help, anyway and if you think of anything else, I'm all ears :-)